# How to check ship to a different address option is enabled or not in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I want to check `ship to a different address option` is enable or not from admin in a custom theme template file.

I have tried filter hook but not usefull.

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_ship_to_different_address_checked', 'filter_woocommerce_ship_to_different_address_checked', 10, 1 );
```

Anyone please help me how can I check a condition that `ship to a different address option` is enabled or not using template file.

Answer (score 1):

Your callback function is missing

So you get:

```php
// Open “Ship to A Different Address” by Default @ WooCommerce Checkout
function filter_woocommerce_ship_to_different_address_checked ( $bool ) {
    // True
    $bool = true;
    
    return $bool;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_ship_to_different_address_checked', 'filter_woocommerce_ship_to_different_address_checked', 10, 1 );
```

Or in short

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_ship_to_different_address_checked', '__return_true' );
```

Replace `true` with `false` for the reverse

---

---

If you want to check the current status, you can do this via

```php
$ship_to_destination = get_option( 'woocommerce_ship_to_destination' );

echo 'Result = ' . $ship_to_destination;
```

Comment: Yes, I have tried this but I want to put checkbox option after shipping address or after payment options, Is it possible?

Comment: @RohanVarma The rule on stackoverflow is one question at a time. I believe that my answer has answered your question. If you have new / other questions you can always open a new topic