# WooCommerce Checkout: How to programmatically trigger the checkbox "Ship to a different address?"

Tags: javascript, wordpress, woocommerce

I have to programmatically trigger the checkbox "Ship to a different address?" with JavaSript and not PHP. How do I simulate a click on this checkbox with JavaScript?

This is my current code for it:

```
const shippingLabel = $('#ship-to-different-address');
shippingLabel.find('input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked', true).change(); // This line should work, but it doesn't work completly
shippingLabel.find('input[type=checkbox]').prop('disabled', true);
shippingLabel.find('span').text('Some new text');
```

Unfortunately, I have a problem that the validation in the checkout suddenly no longer works. For example, if I leave out my first name, it is no longer validated.

[image]
(The picture is in German. "Vorname" is the required first name. It's ignored when I trigger the checkbox programmatically ).

If I click on "Ship to a different address?" normally with the mouse, the validation-error does not occur. What could be the reason?

How to programmatically trigger the checkbox "Ship to a different address?"

Comment: Someone flagged this post as duplicated and pointed to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66167373/how-to-check-ship-to-a-different-address-option-is-enabled-or-not-in-woocommerce). However, it's not what I'm looking for. I just want to simulate a click on the checkbox with JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:

`$("#ship-to-different-address-checkbox").click();`

Not sure why the other options didn't work, but `click()` does.